# How to store new data under new unique id?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to JAVA. Anyone have any idea how to create a loop that is like, the program will get a date value and several set of numerical data or variable, and then i want to store all those data under a unique id. Then if the program get a new date, it will create a new unique id and will store the new data under those new id. I already know how to create the unique id, I just don't have the idea on what kinda loop should i use. Or is there any other way?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M");
    Date d1= sdf.parse(date);
    long millis = d1.getTime();
    long millis1 = 0;
    String id2;

    PointValue pointValue = new PointValue(millis,step);
    String id = reff3.push().getKey();
    id2=id;
    reff3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chartTable");

    if (millis!=millis1){
        id = reff3.push().getKey();
        reff3.child(id).setValue(pointValue);
    }
    else {
        reff3.child(id2).setValue(pointValue);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide us to help you what you tried already.

Comment: Why is some of your code indented?

Comment: What is `reff3` in line 7?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code was unnecessarily hard to read because of inconsistent indentation. When asking people to help you here (or elsewhere) I believe that the least you can do is to provide the best readable code you can. Your IDE (such as Android Studio or Eclipse) can fix that indentation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## month-day handling

Your code parsing a string with `SimpleDateFormat` may vary in its results because you ignore the crucial issue of time zone.

### *java.time*

Never use `java.util.Date` class. The date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

> SimpleDateFormat("d.M")

For a month with day-of-month, use [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d.M" ) ;
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse( "23.1" , f ) ;
```

> monthDay.toString(): --01-23

Notice how that class generates text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I suggest you use that format as well in place of your "d.M" format.

I do not know what you were doing in getting a count of milliseconds since epoch reference with only a month and day, and no time zone to provide context. I will assume you were trying to get the first moment of the day for that date as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```
int year = Year.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).getValue() ;
LocalDate localDate = monthDay.atYear( year ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2020-01-23T00:00Z

Get a count of milliseconds since epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC by extracting a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2020-01-23T00:00:00Z
>
> millis: 1579737600000

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RohBzg).

Put that together.

```
long millis = 
        MonthDay
        .parse( 
            "23.1" , 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d.M" )
        )
        .atYear(
            Year.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).getValue()
        )
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )
        .toInstant()
        .toEpochMilli() 
;
```

As for the rest of your Question asking about looping, the matter is unclear. I suggest you edit to give more explanation as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you mean that u want to store an object's class using loop ? for example we've a class called Person , and its object declared in another class (suppose Person per1[])  within a method of the second class that inserts elements in person's constructor

Comment: no, no an object's class, i've just included the code. I want to store the pointValue under it specfic id for certain date. So, when new date come in, it will create new id and will store the pointValue under those new id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data in a separate node per date, you can:

1. Determine the current date
2. Format that into a string
3. Use that string as the key for the node

In code that'd look something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
Date now = new Date();
String key = sdf.format(now); // just the date part

PointValue pointValue = new PointValue(millis, now.getTime());
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chartTable");

ref.child(key).push(pointValue);
```

You'll note that I use a different date format than you did. I'd **highly** recommend using this format, as it'll make it easier to later get a range of dates.

Aside from this, this now creates a structure like:

```
"chartTable": {
  "2020-06-13": {
    "-Masd9823e39yads": {
      ... your millis and step from PointValue
    }
  }
}
```